# sonata_type_model - Set value to empty

Tags: sonata-admin

Is there a way to allow to set an empty value in the `sonata_type_model`?
This is my current configuration:

```
->add('location', 'sonata_type_model', [
    'class' => Location::class,
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => 'Herkunft',
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `'empty_value' => ''` to the array.

Comment: I get `The option "empty_value" does not exist.` Only `empty_data` but that has no effect. I want to set the current value to empty for existing data (not a default value for new entries). Like `<select><option></option>...</select>`

Comment: That's embarassing, i understand what you want to do and this option is supposed to achieve it perfectly. What is your sonata admin version in composer.json ?

Comment: My composer.json for sonata: `sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.13", "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",`

Comment: Actually i've found something : are you using symfony 3+ ? if so, try `'placeholder' => ''` instead, `empty_value` option doesn't seem to exist anymore on this symfony version

Comment: Almost. When I open the entity, the select box is empty and I can save it without an value. But when I have a entity with a value, I cant set it to empty. There is neither a empty value in the select box nor I can delete the current value with backspace

Comment: Oh there is no little cross like this on the select box : https://i.gyazo.com/a18ed92668dfa813b3926224bf9ca1e7.png ? if not, I don't know how to add it, i see nothing about it in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I solved it with the help of Saving Hooks: `preUpdate()`

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->request->get($this->getForm()->getName())['location']) {
        $object->setLocation(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Changed sonata_type_model to symfony entity type field
// Then add placeholder option witch recognized as empty value option in select box.

...    
    ->add('location', null, [
        'class' => Location::class,
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'Herkunft',
        'placeholder' => 'Your empty option label',
    ])
```